# Spring Data JPA native query does not return correct result

Tags: hibernate, spring-data-jpa

I have the following code where I am trying to obtain an Integer:

```
woID = (Integer) this.em.createNativeQuery("SELECT fk_workorderid FROM manufacturing.workorders_todos WHERE fk_todoid = ?1")
            .setParameter(1, todoID)
            .getResultList()
            .stream()
            .findFirst()
            .orElse(null);
LOGGER.debug("After native query Todo ID: "+todoID+" / WO ID: "+woID);
```

In the logs, this is what I see:

> 2018-09-25 11:45:25,691 https-jsse-nio-8493-exec-8 DEBUG hibernate.SQL
>   - SELECT fk_workorderid FROM manufacturing.workorders_todos WHERE fk_todoid = ?
>
> 2018-09-25 11:45:25,691 https-jsse-nio-8493-exec-8 DEBUG loader.Loader
>   - bindNamedParameters() 102754 -> 1 [1]
>
> 2018-09-25 11:45:25,691 https-jsse-nio-8493-exec-8 TRACE
>   sql.BasicBinder - binding parameter [1] as [INTEGER] - [102754]
>
> 2018-09-25 11:45:25,691 https-jsse-nio-8493-exec-8 DEBUG
>   manufacturing.ToDoFunctions - After native query Todo ID: 102754 / WO
>   ID: null

However, if I take the SQL and put it in MySQL Workbench, then I get the expected result for woID.  What is wrong that the native query always returns null?

Answer (score 0):

GUI (like mysql workbench) applies and "order by" also if not explicitly defined in  your query. That's why is a good practice to have always and "order by" clause explicitly defined.

In this tutorial you can find techniques how to deal with null values and "order by" in mysql:

https://www.designcise.com/web/tutorial/how-to-order-null-values-first-or-last-in-mysql

Comment: While this may be good to keep in mind, I don't think it is the problem here.  The problem is that I should be getting a single record with an integer value, and instead it is not getting any records and thus I am getting a null value.  I did try your suggestion to make sure, though.

Comment: you are not getting any records also if you remove .findFirst() ? Have you tried to place todoID value in ?1, and remove .setParameter(1, todoID), just to test if the result is always empty?

Comment: Yes, I've tried quite a few things, including putting the query in a repository (so there is no findFirst or anything like that).  I also tried to hard code a value of todoID and I still get a null result.  What is even more baffling is that this code is within a reusable function, and it is working fine everywhere else it is called.  It is almost like the query is not actually running in this case, but I don't know how or why that could happen.